# How do you convert .bat to .exe?

Tags: windows, batch-file, iexpress

I've heard that you can do this without downloading software, and that it's done by using *iexpress* and *.bat* files.

But I can't do it with *iexpress* or *batch files*, so I'm wondering how you do it.

And yes, I've tried *admin.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://superuser.com/questions/868340/how-can-i-convert-a-windows-batch-script-to-a-exe

Comment: Yes!! Both methods work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several tools that can convert batch to exe but it is not a good idea since they usually get detected as virus by most anti-viruses after the conversion.

But here you can follow some step-by-step:
https://adamtheautomator.com/bat-to-exe/